# how to make recurrence in SED (too complicated solution)

Tags: regex, sed, recurrence

I have a very big file (>20GB, [grepped part of file](http://www.filedropper.com/dbout)) with dump of LDAP db.

**Same grepped output:**

```
P[containerVrsn:U(0)recordVrsn:U(0)size:U(188)ownGid:G[mdp:U(1090171286)seqNo:U(4920)]logicalDbNo:U(1)classVrsn:U(1)timeStamp:U(0)dbRecord:T[classNo:U(1064620)size:U(160)updateVersion:U(3)checksum:U(1696878703)EPC_SubscriberPot:R[userId:S12("123456789123")groups:A1[ix0:S0("")]services:A0[]blacklist_services:A0[]operatorInfo:A1[ix0:S17("roamingAllowed:NO")]pccSubscriberPotRef:M0[]notificationData:A0[]familyId:S0("")trafficIds:A0[]]]]
P[containerVrsn:U(0)recordVrsn:U(0)size:U(232)ownGid:G[mdp:U(1090171286)seqNo:U(4921)]logicalDbNo:U(1)classVrsn:U(1)timeStamp:U(0)dbRecord:T[classNo:U(1064620)size:U(204)updateVersion:U(102)checksum:U(607801120)EPC_SubscriberPot:R[userId:S12("123456789123")groups:A1[ix0:S44("g_monthly_30Mb_pred:1130:26-09-2015T23:21:19")]services:A0[]blacklist_services:A0[]operatorInfo:A1[ix0:S17("roamingAllowed:NO")]pccSubscriberPotRef:M0[]notificationData:A0[]familyId:S0("")trafficIds:A0[]]]]
P[containerVrsn:U(0)recordVrsn:U(0)size:U(188)ownGid:G[mdp:U(1090171286)seqNo:U(4922)]logicalDbNo:U(1)classVrsn:U(1)timeStamp:U(0)dbRecord:T[classNo:U(1064620)size:U(160)updateVersion:U(85)checksum:U(1685673318)EPC_SubscriberPot:R[userId:S12("123456789123")groups:A1[ix0:S0("")]services:A0[]blacklist_services:A0[]operatorInfo:A1[ix0:S17("roamingAllowed:NO")]pccSubscriberPotRef:M0[]notificationData:A0[]familyId:S0("")trafficIds:A0[]]]]
P[containerVrsn:U(0)recordVrsn:U(0)size:U(232)ownGid:G[mdp:U(1090171286)seqNo:U(4923)]logicalDbNo:U(1)classVrsn:U(1)timeStamp:U(0)dbRecord:T[classNo:U(1064620)size:U(204)updateVersion:U(12)checksum:U(841837929)EPC_SubscriberPot:R[userId:S12("123456789123")groups:A1[ix0:S42("g_monthly_30Mb_pred:13:19-09-2015T23:36:25")]services:A0[]blacklist_services:A0[]operatorInfo:A1[ix0:S17("roamingAllowed:NO")]pccSubscriberPotRef:M0[]notificationData:A0[]familyId:S0("")trafficIds:A0[]]]]
P[containerVrsn:U(0)recordVrsn:U(0)size:U(188)ownGid:G[mdp:U(1090171286)seqNo:U(4924)]logicalDbNo:U(1)classVrsn:U(1)timeStamp:U(0)dbRecord:T[classNo:U(1064620)size:U(160)updateVersion:U(17)checksum:U(1715232109)EPC_SubscriberPot:R[userId:S12("123456789123")groups:A1[ix0:S0("")]services:A0[]blacklist_services:A0[]operatorInfo:A1[ix0:S17("roamingAllowed:NO")]pccSubscriberPotRef:M0[]notificationData:A0[]familyId:S0("")trafficIds:A0[]]]]
P[containerVrsn:U(0)recordVrsn:U(0)size:U(188)ownGid:G[mdp:U(1090171286)seqNo:U(4925)]logicalDbNo:U(1)classVrsn:U(1)timeStamp:U(0)dbRecord:T[classNo:U(1064620)size:U(160)updateVersion:U(3)checksum:U(1831293547)EPC_SubscriberPot:R[userId:S12("123456789123")groups:A1[ix0:S0("")]services:A0[]blacklist_services:A0[]operatorInfo:A1[ix0:S17("roamingAllowed:NO")]pccSubscriberPotRef:M0[]notificationData:A0[]familyId:S0("")trafficIds:A0[]]]]
P[containerVrsn:U(0)recordVrsn:U(0)size:U(188)ownGid:G[mdp:U(1090171286)seqNo:U(4926)]logicalDbNo:U(1)classVrsn:U(1)timeStamp:U(0)dbRecord:T[classNo:U(1064620)size:U(160)updateVersion:U(5)checksum:U(1814191975)EPC_SubscriberPot:R[userId:S12("123456789123")groups:A1[ix0:S0("")]services:A0[]blacklist_services:A0[]operatorInfo:A1[ix0:S17("roamingAllowed:NO")]pccSubscriberPotRef:M0[]notificationData:A0[]familyId:S0("")trafficIds:A0[]]]]
P[containerVrsn:U(0)recordVrsn:U(0)size:U(188)ownGid:G[mdp:U(1090171286)seqNo:U(4927)]logicalDbNo:U(1)classVrsn:U(1)timeStamp:U(0)dbRecord:T[classNo:U(1064620)size:U(160)updateVersion:U(7)checksum:U(1714312039)EPC_SubscriberPot:R[userId:S12("123456789123")groups:A1[ix0:S0("")]services:A0[]blacklist_services:A0[]operatorInfo:A1[ix0:S17("roamingAllowed:NO")]pccSubscriberPotRef:M0[]notificationData:A0[]familyId:S0("")trafficIds:A0[]]]]
P[containerVrsn:U(0)recordVrsn:U(0)size:U(232)ownGid:G[mdp:U(1090171286)seqNo:U(4928)]logicalDbNo:U(1)classVrsn:U(1)timeStamp:U(0)dbRecord:T[classNo:U(1064620)size:U(204)updateVersion:U(60)checksum:U(694242598)EPC_SubscriberPot:R[userId:S12("123456789123")groups:A1[ix0:S44("g_monthly_30Mb_pred:1130:25-09-2015T19:50:04")]services:A0[]blacklist_services:A0[]operatorInfo:A1[ix0:S17("roamingAllowed:NO")]pccSubscriberPotRef:M0[]notificationData:A0[]familyId:S0("")trafficIds:A0[]]]]
P[containerVrsn:U(0)recordVrsn:U(0)size:U(224)ownGid:G[mdp:U(1090171286)seqNo:U(4929)]logicalDbNo:U(1)classVrsn:U(1)timeStamp:U(0)dbRecord:T[classNo:U(1064620)size:U(196)updateVersion:U(20)checksum:U(678693063)EPC_SubscriberPot:R[userId:S12("123456789123")groups:A1[ix0:S34("g_m_q_3GB:1170:30-09-2015T21:41:41")]services:A0[]blacklist_services:A0[]operatorInfo:A1[ix0:S17("roamingAllowed:NO")]pccSubscriberPotRef:M0[]notificationData:A0[]familyId:S0("")trafficIds:A0[]]]]
P[containerVrsn:U(0)recordVrsn:U(0)size:U(420)ownGid:G[mdp:U(1118178710)seqNo:U(4868)]logicalDbNo:U(1)classVrsn:U(1)timeStamp:U(0)dbRecord:T[classNo:U(1091971)size:U(392)updateVersion:U(3673)checksum:U(208178972)EPC_UsageControlAccumulatedPot:R[subscriberId:S12("123456789123")usageControlAccum:S382("{\"reportingGroups\":[{\"absoluteAccumulated\":{\"bidirVolume\":31460668,\"previousExpiryDate\":{\"time\":\"25-12-2014T18:19:45\",\"volume\":\"25-12-2014T18:19:45\"}},\"name\":\"5000\",\"restartInfo\":\"25-12-2014T18:19:45\",\"selected\":\"yes\",\"subscriberGroupName\":\"g_monthly_30Mb_pred\",\"subscriptionDate\":\"25-12-2014T18:19:45\",\"validityTime\":0}],\"version\":\"2.1\"}\n")]]]
P[containerVrsn:U(0)recordVrsn:U(0)size:U(420)ownGid:G[mdp:U(1118178710)seqNo:U(4869)]logicalDbNo:U(1)classVrsn:U(1)timeStamp:U(0)dbRecord:T[classNo:U(1091971)size:U(392)updateVersion:U(269)checksum:U(255165461)EPC_UsageControlAccumulatedPot:R[subscriberId:S12("123456789123")usageControlAccum:S382("{\"reportingGroups\":[{\"absoluteAccumulated\":{\"bidirVolume\":20419748,\"previousExpiryDate\":{\"time\":\"19-09-2015T23:36:25\",\"volume\":\"19-09-2015T23:36:25\"}},\"name\":\"5000\",\"restartInfo\":\"19-09-2015T23:36:25\",\"selected\":\"yes\",\"subscriberGroupName\":\"g_monthly_30Mb_pred\",\"subscriptionDate\":\"19-09-2015T23:36:25\",\"validityTime\":0}],\"version\":\"2.1\"}\n")]]]
P[containerVrsn:U(0)recordVrsn:U(0)size:U(120)ownGid:G[mdp:U(1118178710)seqNo:U(4870)]logicalDbNo:U(1)classVrsn:U(1)timeStamp:U(0)dbRecord:T[classNo:U(1091971)size:U(92)updateVersion:U(10)checksum:U(171763356)EPC_UsageControlAccumulatedPot:R[subscriberId:S12("123456789123")usageControlAccum:S46("{\"reportingGroups\":[],\"version\":\"2.1\"}\n")]]]
P[containerVrsn:U(0)recordVrsn:U(0)size:U(420)ownGid:G[mdp:U(1118178710)seqNo:U(4871)]logicalDbNo:U(1)classVrsn:U(1)timeStamp:U(0)dbRecord:T[classNo:U(1091971)size:U(392)updateVersion:U(686)checksum:U(144346640)EPC_UsageControlAccumulatedPot:R[subscriberId:S12("123456789123")usageControlAccum:S382("{\"reportingGroups\":[{\"absoluteAccumulated\":{\"bidirVolume\":29013670,\"previousExpiryDate\":{\"time\":\"13-12-2014T23:19:19\",\"volume\":\"13-12-2014T23:19:19\"}},\"name\":\"5000\",\"restartInfo\":\"13-12-2014T23:19:19\",\"selected\":\"yes\",\"subscriberGroupName\":\"g_monthly_30Mb_pred\",\"subscriptionDate\":\"13-12-2014T23:19:19\",\"validityTime\":0}],\"version\":\"2.1\"}\n")]]]
P[containerVrsn:U(0)recordVrsn:U(0)size:U(120)ownGid:G[mdp:U(1118178710)seqNo:U(4872)]logicalDbNo:U(1)classVrsn:U(1)timeStamp:U(0)dbRecord:T[classNo:U(1091971)size:U(92)updateVersion:U(185)checksum:U(92726418)EPC_UsageControlAccumulatedPot:R[subscriberId:S12("123456789123")usageControlAccum:S46("{\"reportingGroups\":[],\"version\":\"2.1\"}\n")]]]
P[containerVrsn:U(0)recordVrsn:U(0)size:U(420)ownGid:G[mdp:U(1118178710)seqNo:U(4873)]logicalDbNo:U(1)classVrsn:U(1)timeStamp:U(0)dbRecord:T[classNo:U(1091971)size:U(392)updateVersion:U(139)checksum:U(247172114)EPC_UsageControlAccumulatedPot:R[subscriberId:S12("123456789123")usageControlAccum:S382("{\"reportingGroups\":[{\"absoluteAccumulated\":{\"bidirVolume\":31612708,\"previousExpiryDate\":{\"time\":\"29-11-2014T04:14:03\",\"volume\":\"29-11-2014T04:14:03\"}},\"name\":\"5000\",\"restartInfo\":\"29-11-2014T04:14:03\",\"selected\":\"yes\",\"subscriberGroupName\":\"g_monthly_30Mb_pred\",\"subscriptionDate\":\"29-11-2014T04:14:03\",\"validityTime\":0}],\"version\":\"2.1\"}\n")]]]
P[containerVrsn:U(0)recordVrsn:U(0)size:U(420)ownGid:G[mdp:U(1118178710)seqNo:U(4874)]logicalDbNo:U(1)classVrsn:U(1)timeStamp:U(0)dbRecord:T[classNo:U(1091971)size:U(392)updateVersion:U(12196)checksum:U(714375199)EPC_UsageControlAccumulatedPot:R[subscriberId:S12("123456789123")usageControlAccum:S382("{\"reportingGroups\":[{\"absoluteAccumulated\":{\"bidirVolume\":32961591,\"previousExpiryDate\":{\"time\":\"25-09-2015T19:50:04\",\"volume\":\"25-09-2015T19:50:04\"}},\"name\":\"5000\",\"restartInfo\":\"25-09-2015T19:50:04\",\"selected\":\"yes\",\"subscriberGroupName\":\"g_monthly_30Mb_pred\",\"subscriptionDate\":\"25-09-2015T19:50:04\",\"validityTime\":0}],\"version\":\"2.1\"}\n")]]]
P[containerVrsn:U(0)recordVrsn:U(0)size:U(412)ownGid:G[mdp:U(1118178710)seqNo:U(4875)]logicalDbNo:U(1)classVrsn:U(1)timeStamp:U(0)dbRecord:T[classNo:U(1091971)size:U(384)updateVersion:U(64555)checksum:U(3993616217)EPC_UsageControlAccumulatedPot:R[subscriberId:S12("123456789123")usageControlAccum:S372("{\"reportingGroups\":[{\"absoluteAccumulated\":{\"bidirVolume\":29110847,\"previousExpiryDate\":{\"time\":\"30-09-2015T21:41:41\",\"volume\":\"30-09-2015T21:41:41\"}},\"name\":\"5000\",\"restartInfo\":\"30-09-2015T21:41:41\",\"selected\":\"yes\",\"subscriberGroupName\":\"g_m_q_3GB\",\"subscriptionDate\":\"30-09-2015T21:41:41\",\"validityTime\":0}],\"version\":\"2.1\"}\n")]]]
P[containerVrsn:U(0)recordVrsn:U(0)size:U(120)ownGid:G[mdp:U(1118178710)seqNo:U(4876)]logicalDbNo:U(1)classVrsn:U(1)timeStamp:U(0)dbRecord:T[classNo:U(1091971)size:U(92)updateVersion:U(1427)checksum:U(162455704)EPC_UsageControlAccumulatedPot:R[subscriberId:S12("123456789123")usageControlAccum:S46("{\"reportingGroups\":[],\"version\":\"2.1\"}\n")]]]
P[containerVrsn:U(0)recordVrsn:U(0)size:U(420)ownGid:G[mdp:U(1118178710)seqNo:U(4877)]logicalDbNo:U(1)classVrsn:U(1)timeStamp:U(0)dbRecord:T[classNo:U(1091971)size:U(392)updateVersion:U(166)checksum:U(261918226)EPC_UsageControlAccumulatedPot:R[subscriberId:S12("123456789123")usageControlAccum:S382("{\"reportingGroups\":[{\"absoluteAccumulated\":{\"bidirVolume\":31471028,\"previousExpiryDate\":{\"time\":\"31-05-2015T13:14:46\",\"volume\":\"31-05-2015T13:14:46\"}},\"name\":\"5000\",\"restartInfo\":\"31-05-2015T13:14:46\",\"selected\":\"yes\",\"subscriberGroupName\":\"g_monthly_30Mb_pred\",\"subscriptionDate\":\"31-05-2015T13:14:46\",\"validityTime\":0}],\"version\":\"2.1\"}\n")]]]
```

I've found sed command which rotates one part of this script into some delimited text format. I've read SED documentation and changed this script. This allowed me to get other needed information but I've faced with limitations of `sed` stored string (up to 9) and wondering if it's possible to make it in recurrence.

**Changed Script**

```
cat ./databaseBackup/database_output.txt | \
sed -n '
#found part with changes
'/EPC_SubscriberPot/' {
        s/.*userId.*("\(.*\)")groups.*("\(g_.*\)\(g_.*\)\(g_.*\)\(g_.*\)\(g_.*\)\(g_.*\)")]services.*/\1|\2\n\1|\3\n\1|\4\n\1|\5\n\1|\6\n\1|\7/w file1.log
        s/.*userId.*("\(.*\)")groups.*("\(g_.*\)\(g_.*\)\(g_.*\)\(g_.*\)\(g_.*\)")]services.*/\1|\2\n\1|\3\n\1|\4\n\1|\5\n\1|\6/w file1.log
        s/.*userId.*("\(.*\)")groups.*("\(g_.*\)\(g_.*\)\(g_.*\)\(g_.*\)")]services.*/\1|\2\n\1|\3\n\1|\4\n\1|\5/w file1.log
        s/.*userId.*("\(.*\)")groups.*("\(g_.*\)\(g_.*\)\(g_.*\)")]services.*/\1|\2\n\1|\3\n\1|\4/w file1.log
        s/.*userId.*("\(.*\)")groups.*("\(g_.*\)\(g_.*\)")]services.*/\1|\2\n\1|\3/w file1.log
        s/.*userId.*("\(.*\)")groups.*("\(g_.*\)")]services.*/\1|\2/w file1.log
        s/.*userId.*("\(.*\)")groups.*/\1|/w file1.log
}
#added part
'/EPC_UsageControlAccumulatedPot/' {                                                                                          
        s/.*subscriberId.*("\(.*\)")usageControlAccum.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*/\1|\2\n\1|\3\n\1|\4\n\1|\5\n\1|\6\n\1|\7\n\1|\8\n\1|\9/w file2.log
        s/.*subscriberId.*("\(.*\)")usageControlAccum.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*/\1|\2\n\1|\3\n\1|\4\n\1|\5\n\1|\6\n\1|\7\n\1|\8/w file2.log
        s/.*subscriberId.*("\(.*\)")usageControlAccum.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*/\1|\2\n\1|\3\n\1|\4\n\1|\5\n\1|\6\n\1|\7/w file2.log
        s/.*subscriberId.*("\(.*\)")usageControlAccum.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*/\1|\2\n\1|\3\n\1|\4\n\1|\5\n\1|\6/w file2.log
        s/.*subscriberId.*("\(.*\)")usageControlAccum.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*/\1|\2\n\1|\3\n\1|\4\n\1|\5/w file2.log
        s/.*subscriberId.*("\(.*\)")usageControlAccum.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*/\1|\2\n\1|\3\n\1|\4/w file2.log
        s/.*subscriberId.*("\(.*\)")usageControlAccum.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*/\1|\2\n\1|\3/w file2.log
        s/.*subscriberId.*("\(.*\)")usageControlAccum.*\(bidirVolume....*\)."...subscriptionDate.*/\1|\2/w file2.log
}'

#working with improved output to avoid sed limitation
cat ./file2.log | sed -n '
        s/\([0-9]*\)|bidirVolume...\([0-9]*\),..*expiryDate.*.subscriberGroupName.....\(.*\)/\1|\2|\3/Iw file2_1.log
'
```

**Short description of strings:**

1. Strings with EPC_UsageControlAccumulatedPot contains accumulated
   usage of data counter for particular subscriber. From this row I
   need following information subscriber id, {accumulated usage,
   package name}* more than 7 packages could be found. If I would try to save all needed patterns from first try and if there are more than 4 packages at a time then I would reach limitation of 9 saved patterns. So I have to make this with two tries. First try creates another file with subscriber|pack 1 on line and 2nd sed command would separate this data.

**The questions are:**

1. is it possible to make recurrence to avoid intermediate files
2. is it possible to speedup sed with changing of regular expressions

**Here is the needed output:**

```
# head file1_s.log 
123456789123|
123456789123|g_m_q_3GB:17:15-09-2015T19:45:29
123456789123|g_m_q_3GB:17:06-09-2015T17:54:44
123456789123|g_monthly_1Gb_64kb:1160:26-09-2015T16:09:25
123456789123|

# head file2_1.log 
123456789123|31460668|g_monthly_30Mb_pred
123456789123|20419748|g_monthly_30Mb_pred
123456789123|29013670|g_monthly_30Mb_pred
123456789123|31612708|g_monthly_30Mb_pred
```

Comment: I think `sed` is the wrong tool for this job.  You should probably be using Perl or Python, though another scripting language, possibly even `awk`, might be usable.  The `S382` nomenclature before a JSON-ish string at the end of some of the lines is going to give problems unless you're using a scripting language; it isn't going to be trivial even with a scripting language.  But I would not attempt this with `sed` — I can use `sed`, and it can do some very clever things, but this is not what it was really designed for.  You _should_ also show the desired output from your script.

Comment: `2. is it possible to speedup sed with changing of regular expressions ?`
                                                                                                 
    you can add lazy quantifiers to greedy (.*) to reduce the back tracking of `regex` engine to speedup the process. So you may need to replace `.*` with `.*?`

Answer (score 0):

As [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) suggested i've **switched my researches to other languages**. Before this i've used sed as it's specified in initial topic and parse time was more than 4 hours:

**1st try** was perl but i've failed with it because of very slow processing (the problem was in the same way of thinking - just using regular expressions). Worked all night and was not completed even for first part of checks (SubscriberPot).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dt1 = localtime;
print "Started: $dt1\n";
my $file = './databaseBackup/database_output.txt';
my $fileOut1 = './out1.log';

open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";
open my $fo1, ">", $fileOut1 or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while( my $line = <$info>)  {
  if ($line =~ /EPC_SubscriberPot/){
    if ($line =~ /.*groups.*\[.*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\)\]services.*/) {
      #9 packs
      $line =~ /.*userId.*\("(.*?)"\)groups.*\[.*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\)\]services.*/;
      print $fo1 "$1|$2\n$1|$3\n$1|$4\n$1|$5\n$1|$6\n$1|$7\n$1|$8\n$1|$9\n$1|$10\n";
    } elsif ($line =~ /.*groups.*\[.*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\)\]services.*/) {
      #8 packs
      $line =~ /.*userId.*\("(.*?)"\)groups.*\[.*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\)\]services.*/;
      print $fo1 "$1|$2\n$1|$3\n$1|$4\n$1|$5\n$1|$6\n$1|$7\n$1|$8\n$1|$9\n";
    } elsif ($line =~ /.*groups.*\[.*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\)\]services.*/) {
      #7 packs
      $line =~ /.*userId.*\("(.*?)"\)groups.*\[.*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\)\]services.*/;
      print $fo1 "$1|$2\n$1|$3\n$1|$4\n$1|$5\n$1|$6\n$1|$7\n$1|$8\n";
    } elsif ($line =~ /.*groups.*\[.*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\)\]services.*/) {
      #6 packs
      $line =~ /.*userId.*\("(.*?)"\)groups.*\[.*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\)\]services.*/;
      print $fo1 "$1|$2\n$1|$3\n$1|$4\n$1|$5\n$1|$6\n$1|$7\n";
    } elsif ($line =~ /.*groups.*\[.*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\)\]services.*/) {
      #5 packs
      $line =~ /.*userId.*\("(.*?)"\)groups.*\[.*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\)\]services.*/;
      print $fo1 "$1|$2\n$1|$3\n$1|$4\n$1|$5\n$1|$6\n";
    } elsif ($line =~ /.*groups.*\[.*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\)\]services.*/) {
      #4 packs
      $line =~ /.*userId.*\("(.*?)"\)groups.*\[.*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\)\]services.*/;
      print $fo1 "$1|$2\n$1|$3\n$1|$4\n$1|$5\n";
    } elsif ($line =~ /.*groups.*\[.*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\).*\(".*"\)\]services.*/) {
      #3 packs
      $line =~ /.*userId.*\("(.*?)"\)groups.*\[.*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\)\]services.*/;
      print $fo1 "$1|$2\n$1|$3\n$1|$4\n";
    } elsif ($line =~ /.*groups.*\[.*\(".*"\)ix.*\(".*"\)\]services.*/) {
      #2 packs
      $line =~ /.*userId.*\("(.*?)"\)groups.*\[.*\("(.*)"\).*\("(.*)"\)\]services.*/;
      print $fo1 "$1|$2\n$1|$3\n";
    } elsif ($line =~ /.*groups.*\[.*\(".*"\)\]services.*/) {
      #1 pack
      $line =~ /.*userId.*\("(.*?)"\)groups.*\[.*\("(.*)"\)\]services.*/;
      print $fo1 "$1|$2\n";
    } elsif ($line =~ /.*groups.*\[\]services.*/) {
      #no packs
      $line =~ /.*userId.*\("(.*?)"\)groups.*\[\]services.*/;
      print $fo1 "$1|\n";
    }
  }
  if ($line =~ /EPC_UsageControlAccumulatedPot/){
  }
}

close $info;
close $fo1;

my $dt2 = localtime;

print "Finished: $dt2\n";
```

**2nd try** was awk but this time i've tried another method which was - partial parse with post processing and additional parsing. And speed increased up to ~25 minutes.

```
->./readFile.pl 
Started: Wed Oct  7 18:47:25 2015
Finished: Wed Oct  7 18:53:26 2015

->cat ./readFile.pl

#!/bin/bash

echo "Clear old data"
rm -f repSubsc.txt
rm -f repAccum.txt

echo "Fetch started: `date "+%Y-%m-%d %T"`"
egrep "EPC_UsageControlAccumulatedPot|EPC_SubscriberPot" ./databaseBackup/database_output.txt | awk '
BEGIN{
  x=0;
  str = "";
  fSubsc="repSubsc.txt";
  fAccum="repAccum.txt";
}
{
  if (index($0,"EPC_SubscriberPot")>0) {
    str = gensub(/.*userId.*\("(.*)"\)groups.*\[(.*)\]services.*/, "\\1|\\2", "g", $0);
    split(str,arr,"|");
    msisdn=arr[1];
    str=arr[2];
    x=split(str,arr,"ix");
    if (x > 0) {
      for (i=2;i<=x;i++){
        if (arr[i]!="" && (arr[i] !~ /.*\(""\)/)) {
          str = gensub(/.*\("(.*)"\)/,"\\1","g",arr[i]);
          print msisdn "|" str > fSubsc;
        } else {
          print msisdn "|" > fSubsc;
        }
      }
    } else {
      print msisdn "|" > fSubsc;
    }
  }

  if (index($0,"EPC_UsageControlAccumulatedPot")>0) {
    str = gensub(/.*subscriberId.*\("(.*)"\)usageControlAccum.*reportingGroups...\[(.*)\]...version.*/, "\\1|\\2", "g", $0);
    split(str,arr,"|");
    msisdn=arr[1];
    str=arr[2];

    x=split(str,arr,"absolute");

    if (x > 0) {
      for (i=2;i<=x;i++){
        if (arr[i]!="" && (arr[i] !~ /.*\(""\)/)) {
          str = gensub(/.*bidirVolume...(.*)...previousExpiryDate.*subscriberGroupName.....(.*).....subscriptionDate.*/,"\\1|\\2","g",arr[i]);
          if (index(str,"expiryDate")>0){
            split(str,arrIn,"|");
            str=substr(arrIn[1],1,index(arrIn[1],",")-1) "|" arrIn[2];
          }
          print msisdn "|" str > fAccum
        } else {
          print msisdn "||" > fAccum
        }
      }
    } else {
      print msisdn "||" > fAccum
    }
  }
}
'

echo "Fetch finished: `date "+%Y-%m-%d %T"` -> Sorting started"
sort -u repSubsc.txt > repSubsc_1.txt
sort -u repAccum.txt > repAccum_1.txt
echo "Done: `date "+%Y-%m-%d %T"`"
```

**3rd try** was perl with translated and reformatted from awk. This time i was wery glad to see that full processing was done in just 6 minutes. I know that this is not the end. I have many gaps in my coding and I have to revise the code. But currently it suits my task...

```
->./readFile_awk.sh 
Clear old data
Fetch started: 2015-10-07 18:55:18
Fetch finished: 2015-10-07 19:19:23 -> Sorting started
Done: 2015-10-07 19:20:07

->cat ./readFile_awk.sh
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dt1 = localtime;
print "Started: $dt1\n";
my $file = './databaseBackup/database_output.txt';
my $fSubsc = 'repSubsc.txt';
my $fAccum = 'repAccum.txt';

my $msisdn = '';
my $str = '';

open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";
open my $fs, ">", $fSubsc or die "Could not open $fSubsc: $!";
open my $fa, ">", $fAccum or die "Could not open $fAccum: $!";

while( my $line = <$info>)  {
  if (index($line, 'EPC_SubscriberPot')>0){
    $line =~ /.*userId.*\("(.*)"\)groups.*\[(.*)\]services.*/;

    $msisdn=$1;
    $str=$2;
    my @arr=split /ix/, $str;
    my $x = @arr;
    if ($x > 0) {
      for (my $i=1;$i<=$x-1;$i++){
        if ($arr[$i] ne "" && ($arr[$i] !~ /.*\(""\)/)) {
          $str =~ /.*\("(.*)"\)/;
          print $fs $msisdn."|$1\n";
        } else {
          print $fs $msisdn."|\n";
        }
      }
    } else {
      print $fs $msisdn."|\n";
    }
  }
  if (index($line, 'EPC_UsageControlAccumulatedPot')>0){
    $line =~ /.*subscriberId.*\("(.*)"\)usageControlAccum.*reportingGroups...(.*)...version.*/;

    $msisdn=$1;
    $str=$2;
    my @arr=split /absolute/, $str;
    my $x = @arr;
    if ($x > 0) {
      if ($x==1) {
        print $fa $msisdn."||\n";
      }
      for (my $i=1;$i<=$x-1;$i++){
        if ($arr[$i] ne "" && ($arr[$i] !~ /.*\(""\)/)) {
          $arr[$i] =~ /.*bidirVolume...(.*)...previousExpiryDate.*subscriberGroupName.....(.*).....subscriptionDate.*/;
      if (defined $1) {$str = $1."|";} else {$str="|";}
          if (defined $1) {$str = $str.$2;}
          if (index($str, 'expiryDate')>0){
            my @arrIn = split /|/, $str;
            $str=substr($arrIn[1],1,index($arrIn[1],",")-1)."|".$arrIn[2];
          }
          print $fa $msisdn."|".$str."\n";
        } else {
          print $fa $msisdn."||";
        }
      }
    } else {
      print $fa $msisdn."||";
    }
  }
}

close $info;
close $fs;
close $fa;

my $dt2 = localtime;

print "Finished: $dt2\n";
```

Comment: This is not the solution to initial topic but it solved my problem. Anyway i am wondering is it possible to make some sort of recurrence using sed or regular expressions? For example:
(a(.*)abc(.*)efg)* would find $1.1 $1.2 etc. like an array in array.